# how to identify dynamically created jbutton actions

Tags: java, swing

I create two jbuttons in one panel(can be Box).i create same panel dynamically several times in same frame.so if two panels created dynamically those button make with same variable name.But i want to identify buttons one by one for put actions.how to identify dynamically created buttons one by one?

button creating code

```
    public class Jscrollpanetest extends JFrame {

    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    Box box;
    private static int panelCount = 0;

    public Jscrollpanetest() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(15);
        box = Box.createVerticalBox();
        scrollPane.getViewport().add(box);

        this.add(scrollPane);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);


        Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                box.add(new TestPanel(), box.size());

                scrollPane.validate();
            }
        });
        t.setRepeats(true);
        t.start();


    }

    public class TestPanel extends JPanel {

        int myId = panelCount++;

        public TestPanel() {
            this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1));
            JButton up = new JButton("^");
            JLabel rate = new JLabel("1");
            JButton down = new JButton("^");
            JLabel label = new JLabel("" + myId);
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

            this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1000, 200));
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 100));

            this.add(label);
            this.add(up);
            this.add(rate);
            this.add(down);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Jscrollpanetest testScrollPane = new Jscrollpanetest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The panel sold be responsible for its own content and actions

Comment: I think the best answers to this will come down to how to ***design*** the app.  We cannot know the best design until we understand the purpose of these buttons and why they are being added dynamically.  For example, is this a game with the buttons representing playing pieces randomly created by the game engine, which the user must click to gain points, or 'clear them off the playing field'?  If not, then.. what?  Details, please.

Answer (score 0):

If use and dynamic created `ActionListener` there will be no problem. So each button will have its own `ActionListener`.

If using a common `ActionListener` must add tags to each button as extend `JButton`.